# Using PROC SQL in SAS to transpose a table from long to wide

Tags: sql, sas, transpose

I was reviewing Life Imitates Art: ODS Output Data Sets that Look like Listing Output at http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2013/BB/MWSUG-2013-BB12.pdf where the author forces outputted datasets from PROCs to resemble their tabular descriptive output.   The author's code is:

```
proc print data=sashelp.bweight(obs=5); run;

Proc Tabulate MISSING
Data=sashelp.bweight
Out=outequals(drop=_:);
Class ed smoke;
Tables ed, smoke /
 box="(Table in ODS Destination)";
Run;

Proc Print
Data=outequals noobs;
Run;

Proc Transpose
Data=outequals
 Out=twowaytable(drop=_:)
 prefix=smoke;
 By ed;
 ID smoke;
Var N;
Run;
```

I was wondering if there was a pretty way to do this using proc sql because in the past it seemed that proc transpose was inflexible as problems became more complicated.  I came up with a solution (below), but I can't help but wonder if PROC SQL could be used more efficiently.

```
proc sql ; 
create table col2_a as 
select * from outequals where smoke eq 1 and ed = 0 
outer union 
select * from outequals where smoke eq 1 and ed = 1 
outer union 
select * from outequals where smoke eq 1 and ed = 2 
outer union
select * from outequals where smoke eq 1 and ed = 3
;
quit;

proc sql ; 
create table col2_b as 
select monotonic() as key, * 
from col2_a 
; quit;

proc print data=col1_b ; run;

proc sql ; 
create table report as 
select 
a.ed as ed,
a.N as Smokers_HC,
b.n as NonSmokers_HC
from 
col1_b a join col2_b b 
on a.key eq b.key
;quit;
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and what you want the results to look like.

Comment: The sample data is included in my (and presumably anyone else's) installation  of SAS.  The desired result is shown in the author's proc transpose and in my sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer a transpose solution as its dynamic, Proc SQL requires hard coding the answers.

Here's 'a' Proc SQL solution:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select ed, sum(smoke=1) as smoke1, sum(smoke=0) as smoke0
from sashelp.bweight
group by ed
order by ed;
quit;
```

Comment: Cool answer - though it neatly sidesteps transposing the results of the output of a proc tabulate / proc freq / proc report (which was the main idea of the paper I was reading).